# Generate an exe with predefinied settings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I do apologise if i didn't asked correctly in the title.. i don't know how to ask or what to call for what i need.

-
Let's say that i have a simple Application called "TestApp" written in C#.

Inside that application, i have the next variables:

```
int clientid = 123;
string apiurl = "http://somesite/TestApp/api.php";
```

When i have a new client, i need to create a new special TestApp.exe just for him, changing the 'clientid' variable inside the code.

It's possible to automate this process? To change that variable automatically and export an exe without for me to interfere with the process?

-

I asked this because i think/or i'm sure that it's possible because of the next popular examples:

- http://download.cnet.com/2701-20_4-1446.html?tag=sideBar;downloadLinks
  [ It creates a special .exe with a predefinied link from where to download the real file ]
- http://torrent2exe.com/ 
  [ It's embedding the .torrent file to a special .exe just with some custom variables changed, like torrent name or download size ]

Again, i do apologise if i didn't asked my question correctly and for my bad english, trying my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two parts to your question:

1. You want to have variables inside the program based on client for your app
2. You want to automate the process of making the settings changes.

---

**To make custom settings:**

Use `AppSettings`.

First, add a reference to `System.Configuration` assembly.

In your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientID" value="123" />
    <add key="ApiUrl" value="http://somesite/TestApp/api.php" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In your code, to read the settings:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

class Program
{
    private static int clientID;
    private static string apiUrl;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Try to get clientID - example that this is a required field
        if (!int.TryParse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"], out clientID))
            throw new Exception("ClientID in appSettings missing or not an number");

        // Get apiUrl - example that this isn't a required field; you can
        // add string.IsNullOrEmpty() checking as needed
        apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"];

        Console.WriteLine(clientID);
        Console.WriteLine(apiUrl);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[More about AppSettings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

**To automate the creation of settings:**

This all depends on how complex you want to get.

- When you build your project, your `app.config` file becomes `TestApp.exe.config`
- You can use `ConfigurationManager` class to write Config files.
- Further, you can write a little Exe that writes the config file with custom settings and execute it as part of a build action. Lots of ways to accomplish automation which depend on how you intend to deploy your application.

A quick example of writing an app.config file appSettings section programmatically:

```
public static void CreateOtherAppSettings()
{
    Configuration config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("OtherApp.config");

    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ClientID", "456");
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ApiUrl", "http://some.other.api/url");

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But how actually can i deploy the app since it's a standalone .exe, it's there a possibility to auto embed the user.config inside the exe?

Comment: You don't embed it inside the exe - it's always a separate config file. You can generate the config files for each deployment, I've updated my answer and am working on an example.

Comment: @user3280998: See updated answer with example. This should give you enough to run with it and figure out how best to generate the config. I don't know about your project obviously to be more specific, but I've laid out several options and examples for you.